# android:layout_height="0.5dp" will be error

Tags: android

I want to user ImageView like

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0.4dp"
    android:background="@color/bottomline" />
```

but ***android:layout_height="0.4dp*"** is error !

the error:***Suspicious size: this will make the view invisible, should be used with layout_weight.***

And I found that the error will appear if the ***imageview is the first view*** in LinearLayout,like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/backgroundcolor"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- first view error -->

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0.4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@color/bottomline" />

<!-- second view  right -->

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0.4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@color/bottomline" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="李文"
    android:textColor="@color/black_text_color"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
```

how to solve the problem ?

Comment: Are you sure that you want your view points wide? It's not even a pixel

Comment: The error clearly says . This 0.4dp is very small you are not able to see. Add height for example 10dp your error will gone

Comment: The Error clearly says whats the problem in that line. so,give minimum `1dp` for height.

Comment: replace your linerlayout to constraint layout its resolve error

Answer (score 0):

You should try to give height in `px` if to want a thin line.

Comment: px density is not same for all devices, it may vary on hdpi and xhdpi and ...
so not a solution...

Answer (score 0):

The trick is not to use "**wrap_content**" or "**fill_parent**" for the controls you are setting a weight to. Instead set the layout_height to **0px** (when inside a vertical layout) and then the child controls will get proportioned per the weight values

Change  the **layout_height** to **1dp**